# VueJs child component props not updating instantly

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, vue-component

I have a parent/child component setup where the parent is loading data from the server and passing it down to children via props. In the child I would like to instantiate a jQuery calendar with some of the data it receives from the parent.

In order to wait for the data before setting up the calendar, I broadcast an event in the parent that I have an event listener setup for in the child.

The listener is being fired in the child but if I `this.$log('theProp')`, it's undefined. However, if I inspect the components with the VueJs devtools, the parent/child relationship is there and the child has received the prop in the meantime.

The prop is defined on the child as a dynamic prop `:the-prop="theProp"`. Since the child does receive the prop in the end, I'm assuming my setup is correct but there seems to be some sort of delay. The parent sets the props in the return function of the ajax call and again: it's working, just with a slight delay it seems.

I also tried registering a `watch` listener on the prop in the child so I could setup the calendar then and be sure that the prop is there. However, the watch listener fires, but `this.$log('theProp')` is still undefined.

If I pass the data along with the the broadcast call, like `this.$broadcast('dataLoaded', theData)` the child receives it just fine. But it seems wrong to do it that way as I'm basically building my own prop handler.

I'm not posting any code because the components are rather large and the VueJs devtools are telling me the parent/child situation is working.

Am I missing some information? Is there a slight delay between setting a value in the parent and the child receiving it? What would be the proper way to wait for parent data in the child?

Normally, when you're just rendering the data out into the template, the timing doesn't matter so much since the data is bound to the template. But in this case, I really need the data to be there to setup the calendar or it will be wrong.

Thanks.

**edit 1:** here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dr3djo0u/1/
It seems to confirm that the data is not available immediately after the broadcast. However, the watcher does work, though I could almost swear that sometimes `this.$log('someData')` returned `undefined` when I setup that testcase.

But I guess my problem might be somewhere else, I'll have a look tonight, don't have the project with me right now.

**edit 2:** did some more tests. My problem was that a) event listeners do not seem to receive the data instantly and b) I was also trying to init the calendar in the `route.data` callback if `someData` was already around (e.g. when coming from parent), but that route callback is called before the component is ready, so it wasn't working there either.

My solution is now this:

```
// works when the child route is loaded directly and parent finishes loading someData
watch: {
    someData() {
        this.initCalendar();
    }
},

// works when navigating from parent (data already loaded)
ready() {
    if (this.someData && this.someData.length) {
        this.initCalendar()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are `watch`ing a variable and its value inside the `watch` is undefined, something is actually setting it to undefined.

Answer (score 57):

As far as I know, you should not need events to pass data from parent to child.

All you need is, in the child component: `props: ['theProp']`

And when using the child component in the parent: `<child :theProp="someData"></child>`

Now, wherever in the parent you change `someData`, the child component will react accordingly.

You don't need events, you don't need "watch", you don't need "ready".

---

For example: after an AJAX call, in the parent's "ready", you load some data:

```
// at the parent component

data: function () {
  return {
    someData: {}
  }
},

ready: function () {
  var vm = this;
  $.get(url, function(response) {
    vm.someData = response;
  });
}
```

Now, **you do not need anything else to pass the data to the child**. It is already in the child as `theProp`!

What you really need to do is to have, in the child, something which **reacts** to data changes on its own `theProp` property.

Either in the interface:

```
<div v-if="theProp.id > 0">
  Loaded!
</div>
```

Or in JavaScript code:

```
// at the child component

computed: {
  // using a computed property based on theProp's value
  awesomeDate: function() {
    if (!this.theProp || (this.theProp.length === 0)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!this.initialized) {
      this.initCalendar();
    }
    return this.theProp.someThing;
  }
}
```

---

**Update 1**

You can also, in the parent, render the child conditionally:

```
<child v-if="dataLoaded" :theProp="someData"></child>
```

Only set `dataLoaded` to true when the data is available.

**Update 2**

Or maybe your issue is related to a [change detection caveat](http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Maybe you're creating a new property in an object...

```
vm.someObject.someProperty = someValue
```

...when you should do...

```
vm.$set('someObject.someProperty', someValue)
```

...among other "caveats".

**Update 3**

In VueJS 2 you are not restricted to templates. You can use a [render function](https://rc.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html) and code the most complex rendering logic you want.

**Update 4** (regarding OP's **edit 2**)

Maybe you can drop `ready` and use `immediate` option, so your initialization is in a single place:

```
watch: {
  someData: {
    handler: function (someData) {
      // check someData and eventually call
      this.initCalendar();
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Comment: mine worked and the issue was that component was loaded before data are retrieved and since i was assigning child component prop to another variable it was not updating but now using `v-if` it is working, thank you guys

Comment: Try passing :key property to child component initialisation. Like  <child :key="parent.id"></child>

Comment: You say `Now, wherever in the parent you change someData, the child component will react accordingly`, but it's true only for `bool`, `string` and `int` types - not for objects and arrays. For example if `someData` is an object and `someData.someField` changes, then Vue won't handle it's job.

Comment: @Slaus have you find any way for objects and arrays for reactivity? or any work around for objects?

Answer (score 10):

It's because tricky behavior in ***Vue Parent and Child lifecycle hooks***.

Usually parent component *fire* `created()` hook and then `mount()` hook, but when there are child components it's not exactly that way: Parent *fires* `created()` and then his childs fire `created()`, then `mount()` and only after child's `mount()` hooks are loaded, parent loads his `mount()` as explained [here](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f). And that's why the prop in child component isn't loaded.

**Use `mounted()` hook instead `created()`**

like that https://jsfiddle.net/stanimirsp5/xnwcvL59/1/

Answer (score 6):

**Vue 3**

Ok so I've spent like 1.5h trying to find out how to pass prop from parent to child:

**Child**

```js
<!-- Template -->
<template>
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" :value="csrfToken">
  <span>
    {{ csrfToken }}
  </span>
</template>

<!-- Script -->
<script>
export default {
  props: [
    "csrfToken"
  ]
}
</script>
```

**Parent**

```js
<!-- Template -->
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitTestMailForm" v-bind:action="formActionUrl" ref="form" method="POST">
...
    <CsrfTokenInputComponent :csrf-token="csrfToken"/>
...
  </form>
</template>

<!-- Script -->
<script>
...
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      ...
      csrfToken : "",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * @description will handle submission of the form
     */
    submitTestMailForm(){
      let csrfRequestPromise = this.getCsrfToken();

      let ajaxFormData = {
        receiver     : this.emailInput,
        messageTitle : this.titleInput,
        messageBody  : this.bodyTextArea,
        _csrf_token  : this.csrfToken,
      };

      csrfRequestPromise.then( (response) => {
        let csrfTokenResponseDto = CsrfTokenResponseDto.fromAxiosResponse(response);
        this.csrfToken           = csrfTokenResponseDto.csrToken;

        this.axios({
          method : "POST",
          url    : SymfonyRoutes.SEND_TEST_MAIL,
          data   : ajaxFormData,
        }).then( (response) => {
          // handle with some popover
        })
      });
    },
    /**
     * @description will return the csrf token which is required upon submitting the form (Internal Symfony Validation Logic)
     */
    getCsrfToken(){
      ...
      return promise;
    }
  },
  components: {
    CsrfTokenInputComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

**Long story short**

This is how You need to pass down the prop to child

```js
    <CsrfTokenInputComponent :csrf-token="csrfToken"/>
```

**NOT** like this

```
    <CsrfTokenInputComponent csrf-token="csrfToken"/>
```

Even if my IDE keep me telling me `yeap i can navigate with that prop to child` - vue could not bind it.

Comment: In an equally frustrating half hour I just found if you do `props:['CsrfToken']` it wont bind with `<CsrfTokenInputComponent :csrf-token="csrfToken"/>` only if you do `props:['csrfToken']`

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I feel stupid for not finding stuff like that in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

## solution (testing ok)

> In child component just using the `props` data, no need to re-assignment `props`'s values to `data`, it will be cause update bug!

#### vue child component props update bug & solution

[image]

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/child-component-is-not-updated-when-parent-component-model-changes/18283?u=xgqfrms

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not how to pass data with props, but rather how to do two things at almost the same time.

I have an user account component that can edit users (with an user id) and add users (without id).
A child component shows checkboxes for user<->company assignments, and needs the user id to prepare API calls when the user account is saved.

It is important that the child component shows before saving the user account, so that things can be selected before the user is saved and gets an id.
So it has no user id at first: the id is passed to the child component as 'null'.

It updates when the user is stored and gets an id.
But at this point, it takes a very short time for the child to get the new id into its model.
If you call a function in the child component that relies on data that was just changing, it might happen that the function executes before the data is updated.

For cases like this, nextTick() is your friend.

```
import { nextTick } from 'vue';

...

saveAccount() {
      axios.post(URL, this.userModel).then((result)) {
        // our model gets an id when persisted
        this.userModel.id=result.data.id;
        nextTick( () => {
          this.$refs.childComponent.doSomething();
        });
      }
    }
```